# Indesign layout for English / Spanish zine with flipped pages backwards and forwards

Tags: adobe-indesign

We want to create a little magazine for our laundromat.

I'd like it to read in one direction with English and the other direction with Spanish. This way you could just flip it over vertically to switch languages. I've managed to get something that works... but it's not elegant or reusable if I add pages etc.

Any ideas or precedent for a template like this?

Comment: If you can not use the same template on each page, create another one in the same document. Anyway, to understand better your question, put a screenshot please.

Comment: Are you paginating for print? If so it will depend how you are printing. For offset litho you're going to need to know the printer's pagination options; how they fold for any given page count/size. You will need to do that to account for creep if they're folding & stapling. [I've never done this by computer, I used to do it by hand 30 years ago]

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me it would be an easy set up using the Rotate Spread View options in InDesign.

Set up the document to have an English master page and a Spanish master page. It may be easier to *not* use "facing pages". You can still set up spreads. Create the Spanish master page upside down.

[image]

Then go through the piece and design the English half.
When you are ready to design the Spanish half, from the **Pages Panel Menu**, choose `Page Attributes > Rotate Spread View > 180°`

[image]

This will flip the document **view** upside down as well, making the Spanish pages **appear** right-side up.

[image]

This **does not** alter the actual document in *any* way. It merely changes what you *see on screen*, making it easier to work.

Comment: Thanks, @scott. This is what I had begun to do, but didn't want to get to the end and have someone say, "Well, why didn't you do it this way simpler way!"  : )